# rasterio - set compression quality

Tags: python, compression, gdal, rasterio

I know about the possibility in the `rasterio` module to set a compression "family" like `webp` or `JPEG` by using the respective profile. But I want to have more control over the compression quality, like it is possible when using `GDAL`.

Ideally, I want something like this:

```
from osgeo import gdal

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
ds = driver.Create(MYFILE, cols, rows, 1, dtype, ['COMPRESS=JPEG', 'JPEG_QUALITY=90'])
```

I could not find anything in the rasterio [writing](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/writing.html) or [profile](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/profiles.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation here: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/image_options.html#creation-options

Basically the options need to be set when you open the dataset you will write your data to.

So for your specific example it would be something like this:

```
with rasterio.open("output.tif", "w", **src.meta, compress="JPEG",
                   jpeg_quality=90) as dataset:
    # Write data to the dataset.
```

Comment: That was much easier than expected, thank you! Adding to this, I found that in `GDAL` (like `gdal_translate`) the quality keyword then is just `quality` instead of `jpeg_quality` (same also for the `webp` compression).